# Video to FLV code in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am looking for efficient and easy to implement code which work for media file to flv conversion.

Please give me some referral sites or links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a nice shell (windows or unix) script using ffmpeg: http://worldtv.com/blog/guides_tutorials/flv_converter.php.

Use exec() in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php or equivalent to call your script.

I do this to convert sound file to mp3, from web interface, it work perfectly.